# How to configure lxc container to have two ethernet devices - macvlan and bridge?

Tags: networking, server, ethernet, lxc

I'm having trouble with network configuration for lxc containers. I want multiple containers located on one machine to communicate via macvlan with outside world, but also have local bridge to communicate between themselves and host computer.

```
 ------------------------ OUTSIDE WORLD -----------------------------
    ^                          ^                             ^
    |                          |                             |
 macvlan0                   macvlan1                      macvlan2
    |                          |                             |
    v                          v                             v
   HOST <--- bridge0 ---> CONTAINER A <--- bridge0 ---> CONTAINER B
```

It seems like I'm missing something because using **lxc network** I managed to create containers configured for macvlan (they are communicating with outside world just fine, same for outside world communicating with them), I also managed to create containers with bridged connection (that comminicate with host and themselves just great).

The problem I have is that no matter what I do I cannot have two interfaces at the same time. It's always the first one in the network configuration that is working fine. Second one is always present, but IP is not assigned to it and it stays inactive no matter what I try.

I tried so many things that I'm not even sure what should I do anymore. 
How can I proceed with it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with KVM/libvirt, and the following LXD advice was helpful to me:
https://lxd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq/#networking-issues

make sure the host network configuration is handled by `network-manager`, not by `netplan`.

> important thing is to set `stp: false`, otherwise the bridge will sit in `learning` state for up to 10 seconds, which is longer than most DHCP requests last. As there is no possibility of cross-connecting and causing loops, this is safe to do.